# Getting dynamic routing input from HTML

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs

I am using ejs as a templating language .

```
<main class="content">
    <% documents.forEach(function(documentObject) { %>
    <h1><a href="/showprofile/:username"><%= documentObject.username %></a> solved </h1>
    <h2><%= documentObject.problem_id %>. <%= documentObject._statement %> in  
    <%= documentObject.time %>  seconds on  
    <%= documentObject.date_added %> . </h2>
    <% }) %>


</main>
```

I am using a dynamic route `/showprofile/:username` for redirection . I need to make the hyperlink in such a way such that the value of `documentObject.username` gets passed as the parameter to `:username` . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the ejs function to render username in your href attribute instead of `:username`:

```
<h1><a href="/showprofile/<%= documentObject.username %>"><%= documentObject.username %></a> solved </h1>
```

Comment: Hey thanks man ! I was trying it this way `<h1><a href="/showprofile/:<%= documentObject.username %>"><%= documentObject.username %></a> solved </h1>` . Was running into error with the colon . ty :)